# what is the best way to include a template in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a page like  menu bar, tool bar, template panel, footer.
based on my menu i should able to dynamically load the template.

what is the best way to include a template dynamically and pass scope,events... to that template?

->ng-include, ng-view,....
what is the best way

Answer (score 2):

A preferred way is to use ng-include, the included template should instantiate a controller so that you can pull data into it.

```
<ng-include src="path/to/your/template.html" ></ng-include>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ui-router. It is the preferred way to solve this problem.

Within the configuration, you define which partial templates to load for each page, or state.

Then in your index.html you place the ui-view directive. This directive will be replaced with your partial templates.

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to include templates is using directives, because the directives can be used in multiple points of the application, and they are easy to understand.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/docs/guide/directive